# fail installing keybert on python 3.10.4

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

I'm trying to install keybert on python 3.10.4, but it fails on the installation of the scikit-learn library stating a dependencies confilc on Numpy as below:
[ScreenShot of CMD terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekKQJ.jpg)

```
    Using cached meson-0.62.2-py3-none-any.whl (864 kB)
  Collecting Cython<3.0,>=0.29.21
    Using cached Cython-0.29.32-py2.py3-none-any.whl (986 kB)
  Collecting pybind11<2.11.0,>=2.4.3
    Using cached pybind11-2.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (213 kB)
  Collecting pythran<0.12.0,>=0.9.12
    Using cached pythran-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.2 MB)
  Collecting wheel<0.38.0
    Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting numpy==1.22.3
    Using cached numpy-1.22.3-cp310-cp310-win32.whl (12.2 MB)
  ERROR: Cannot install numpy==1.21.6 and numpy==1.22.3 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

  The conflict is caused by:
      The user requested numpy==1.22.3
      The user requested numpy==1.21.6

  To fix this you could try to:
  1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
  2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

  ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

- I have tried to do it in a new virtual env but same.
- Tried to install Numpy 1.22.3 first, then the sciKit-learn library independently but I'm       getting the same dependencies conflict over and over.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: If you try to install `keybert` and `scikit-learn` simultaneously, does `pip` find compatible versions of all the dependencies?  I.e., does this work, `python -m pip install keybert scikit-learn`?

Comment: The scikit-learn library is being installed when installing keybert . Just wanted to install scikit-learn alone first to see if the issue could be coming from the keybert installation process.

Comment: I created a virtual environment, `python -m venv _testenv`, activated the virtual environment, upgraded the python packages in the virtual environment (including `pip`), and then `python -m pip install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy eager keybert`. `keybert` and all of its dependencies were installed without error.

Comment: I created a new VenV and ran your commands line @rickhg12hs. I'm getting the same error out put:

Comment: Strange that when I install `keybert` in my `venv`, many of the packages mentioned in your install are not mentioned in mine.  Why are all your other packages mentioned?

Comment: My successful install ends with, `Successfully installed certifi-2022.9.24 charset-normalizer-2.1.1 click-8.1.3 commonmark-0.9.1 filelock-3.8.0 huggingface-hub-0.10.0 idna-3.4 joblib-1.2.0 keybert-0.6.0 nltk-3.7 numpy-1.23.3 packaging-21.3 pillow-9.2.0 pygments-2.13.0 pyparsing-3.0.9 pyyaml-6.0 regex-2022.9.13 requests-2.28.1 rich-12.6.0 scikit-learn-1.1.2 scipy-1.9.1 sentence-transformers-2.2.2 sentencepiece-0.1.97 threadpoolctl-3.1.0 tokenizers-0.12.1 torch-1.12.1 torchvision-0.13.1 tqdm-4.64.1 transformers-4.22.2 typing-extensions-4.3.0 urllib3-1.26.12`.

Comment: It seems to start as it should, issue are with dependencies needed to run sciKit-Learn---------------->
**>pip install keybert
Collecting keybert
  Using cached keybert-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting rich>=10.4.0
  Using cached rich-12.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (237 kB)
Collecting sentence-transformers>=0.3.8
  Using cached sentence-transformers-2.2.2.tar.gz (85 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting scikit-learn>=0.22.2
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.1.2.tar.gz (7.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error**

Comment: Interesting that your install proceeds with `.tar.gz` files.  When I installed, all `python`wheel (`.whl`) files are used.  I see that some of your install attempt uses, without error, `.whl` files.  I wonder if the `.tar.gz` files aren't used, will your install be successful?  Does `python -m pip install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy eager --only-binary ":all:" keybert` work?

Comment: Infortunately no, it doesn't go through successfully **Collecting keybert
  Using cached keybert-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.18.5
  Using cached numpy-1.23.3-cp310-cp310-win32.whl (12.2 MB)
Collecting keybert
  Using cached keybert-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.1 kB)
ERROR: Cannot install keybert==0.1.0 and keybert==0.6.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    keybert 0.6.0 depends on scikit-learn>=0.22.2
    keybert 0.1.0 depends on scikit-learn>=0.22.2**

Comment: You seem to have multiple versions of packages installed.  If you start with a clean `venv`, upgrade `pip`, `setuptools`, install `wheel`, and then `python -m pip install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy eager --only-binary ":all:" keybert`, there should be no attempt to install multiple versions of packages.

Comment: Thanks you so much rick, i have exactly followed your suggestion. Still getting dependencies issues

Comment: ---> **Collecting keybert
  Using cached keybert-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting rich>=10.4.0
  Using cached rich-12.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (237 kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.18.5
  Using cached numpy-1.23.3-cp310-cp310-win32.whl (12.2 MB)
Collecting keybert
  Using cached keybert-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.1 kB)
ERROR: Cannot install keybert==0.1.0 and keybert==0.6.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    keybert 0.6.0 depends on scikit-learn>=0.22.2
    keybert 0.1.0 depends on scikit-learn>=0.22.2**

Comment: I have no idea why `pip` even tries to install `keybert 0.1.0` when the command should ignore it and install `keybert 0.6.0`.  When I installed `keybert`, only the most recent packages were installed with no mention of other versions.  In a clean `venv`, etc., what happens with `python -m pip install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy eager --only-binary ":all:" "keybert==0.6.0"`

Comment: To give some news on this, i have successfully install keybert. I had multiple version of python in 32 and 64 bits version so cleaned the stuffs up keeping only the 64bits version because the following ----> https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/24604